# JSON Format using org.json

Tags: java, json

I am converting XML message to JSON using org.json classes and conversion works fine however the converted JSON message has root and row elements as shown in below screen shot 1 and our  requirement to have a JSON message with out any root and row as shown in screen shot 2

i tried different way but unsuccessful all times

**XML to JSON converted message**

[image: XML to JSON converted message]

**Requirement is to have JSON Message with out root and row, JSON message should have only "CompanyDetails"**

[image: Required JSON Mesage with out nodes]

Below is the java code which i used to convert to read incomming XML message and convert it to JSON message successfully, now trying to read only "CompanyDetails" and ignore root and row elements
any suggestions on what i am doing wrong to achieve the required JSON message is appreciated

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationInput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationOutput;

public class XML2JSON extends AbstractTransformation {
  @Override
  public void transform(TransformationInput transformationInput, TransformationOutput transformationOutput)
  throws StreamTransformationException {
  InputStream inputStream = transformationInput.getInputPayload().getInputStream();
  OutputStream outputStream = transformationOutput.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream();
  try {
  byte[] buf = new byte[inputStream.available()];
  inputStream.read(buf);
  JSONObject xmlJsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(new String(buf, "utf-8"));
  String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJsonObj.toString(4);
  byte[] bytes = jsonPrettyPrintString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
  outputStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
  getTrace().addDebugMessage("Exception while writing OutputPayload: IOException", e);
  throw new StreamTransformationException(e.toString());
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"please assist on how to update the below code "_ -- Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. We don't do the work for you.  You attempt the task and post a specific question after you run into a problem, providing a detailed description.

Comment: well thank you for the update but let me rephrase i have attempted multiple times with different codes available but all my attempt was unsuccessful, so i have decided to check with experts

Comment: Your required message is an array, not an object

Comment: Thank you the update I am new to json message, can you share any example or any previous post which will help me understand to make the code changes

Comment: Rephrase your question and be specific, and provide detailed description. Check help center.

Comment: Previous post? I mean, the http://json.org is very short itself. Whatever language or libraries you use  are implementation details. JSON is always the same formatting

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
JSONObject xmlJsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(new String(buf, "utf-8"));
```

You need to continue parsing the object down to the rows

```
JSONArray xmlJsonArr = xmlJsonObj.getJSONArray("root")
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .getJSONArray("row");
```

Then write `xmlJsonArr` to the file

Its not clear if the root will have multiple objects in it, but if so, you'll need to loop over the objects of the root array, then build your own JSONArray of all the inner row objects

Comment: i tried as suggested but get error exception: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["root"] not found.Application mapping program XML2JSON throws a stream transformation exception: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["root"] not found.: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["root"] not found.

Comment: According to your image, it's there

Comment: True it is there but the code is not reading it, do we have to enhance the code